# Why does arduino ide tell me I have too many initiallizers?

Tags: c++, list, raspberry-pi2, arduino-uno

I have a sinewave look up table in the form of a list in my arduino program. I used a calculator to generate it. I have confirmed the length of the list with a python 2 shell,
`>>>a=[all the variables  separated by commas]` 
`>>>len(a)`
131300 is the value returned as the number of values in 'a'. So why when I run this code:

```
#include <Wire.h>//Include the Wire library to talk I2C

//This is the I2C Address of the MCP4725, by default (A0 pulled to GND).
#define MCP4725_ADDR 0x60   

//Sinewave Tables were generated using this calculator:
//http://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/Sine-Generator-Calculator.phtml


int lookup = 0;//varaible for navigating through the tables
int sintab2[131300]=
{ 
    /* This is where I put my list. */ 
};


void setup()
{
  Wire.begin();

  // Set A2 and A3 as Outputs to make them our GND and Vcc,
  //which will power the MCP4725
  pinMode(A2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(A3, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(A2, LOW);//Set A2 as GND
  digitalWrite(A3, HIGH);//Set A3 as Vcc
}
//---------------------------------------------------
void loop()
{
  Wire.beginTransmission(MCP4725_ADDR);
  Wire.write(64);                     // cmd to update the DAC
  Wire.write(sintab2[lookup] >> 4);        // the 8 most significant bits...
  Wire.write((sintab2[lookup] & 15) << 4); // the 4 least significant bits...
  Wire.endTransmission();
  lookup = (lookup + 1) & 147454;
}
```

Why am I getting this error, the python shell is telling me my list is 131300 values long.

```
DAC_SINE.cpp:6607:1: error: too many initializers for 'int [16383]'
```

If it is needed I can post my list. The values I entered into the daycounter.com calculator with 131299 for the number of points, 4095 for the max amplitude, 20 numbers per row, and decimal format. Please help.

Comment: Given that 16383 happens to be 2 ** 14 -1, I suspect there's simply a stack limit here... and you cannot have an array of size 131,300...

Comment: Assume `sizeof(int) == 4` a fairly safe assumption for raspberry pi. 16383 * 4 = 65532 which is 1 int away from 65536, 2 to the power of 16. Very likely a memory limit and a misleading error message.

Comment: You don't have enough storage on your raspberry pi.

Comment: Arduino and Raspberry Pi are completely different products, please select the appropriate tag

Comment: The error message you posted suggests the compiler adjusted `int sintab2[131300]` to `int sintab2[16383]`. Were there any earlier warning or error messages that you neglected to post?  (Always post the complete compiler output)

Comment: BTW there is arduino.stackexchange.com